# Unable to access NTFS partitions

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

Initially, I was using Windows 7 home premium. And I decided to switch to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After installation, I am unable to see 500GB partition. The partition consists of important files. Below is the result of commands I found on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Please suggest some solutions ASAP.

```
sv@sv-Aspire-5755G:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 139.7G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 555.1G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

sv@sv-Aspire-5755G:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5 /media/windows
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Comment: Can you still boot into Windows?

Comment: If you can still boot Windows, disable `fast boot` in the power control panel, and disable hibernation in an admin console prompt window `powercfg.exe -h off`. Then you should be able to mount it in Ubuntu. Cheers, Al

Comment: /dev/sda5 isn't your Windows disk - it's the Linux one based on the mount point.  And it's already mounted.  Add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question as an edit please.